# Why is ng-init only allowed for aliasing, and not for assignment or other logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've used `ng-init` probably thousands of times but until today I had never read the (very simple) documentation for it.  According to the docs:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

I'm confused as to why they say you should only use `ng-init` for aliasing? I can think of several simple use cases where doing basic logic in an ng-init is helpful.  Is this just a convention, or is there some other reason/explanation for why we shouldn't use it for anything but aliasing?

For example, if I have

```
$scope.items = [{large:true,count:34},{large:false,count:12},{large:true,count:17}];
```

and I want to get a count of the number of `large` items and the number of items whose `count` is greater than 20, I would have to write a loop in my controller to loop through all the items and get those counts.  But an `ng-repeat` is already looping through all my items for me as it adds them to the DOM. So is really that bad to do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="largeCount = largeCount + (item.large ? 1: 0);"></div>
<p>There are {{largeCount}} large items</p>
```

I'm just wondering if there is some larger reason for not doing any logic inside of an `ng-init` or is it simply to keep all of the "business logic" in the controller and not in the view...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would argue that if the feature is available then why not use it? BUT ... they cautioned me about the use of angular.forEach too. I was specifically told not to try and improve it because they wanted people to quit using it (it was not really meant to be public/exposed). It could be they feel the same way about ng-init. Or maybe they want to remove it in the future and this is just an early warning.

Comment: I believe it's like you said - it's purely to keep business logic in the controller. however I don't know what can I do to support my case.